# Need to select the only one value from multiple element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to fetch the only one value from the multiple elements with some conditions

Input XML:

```
   <PlanMaps>
      <_PlanMaps>
        <PolicyNum>456789</PolicyNum>
      </_PlanMaps>
      <_PlanMaps>
        <PolicyNum>456789</PolicyNum>
      </_PlanMaps>
      <_PlanMaps>
        <PolicyNum>0456789</PolicyNum>
      </_PlanMaps>
    </PlanMaps>
```

XSLT I tried:

```
          <IndexField>
                 <idxName>Number</idxName>
                 <idxValue>
                    <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="PlanMaps/_PlanMaps/PolicyNum[not(starts-with(., '0'))]">
                          <xsl:value-of select="PlanMaps/_PlanMaps/PolicyNum"/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                 </idxValue>
              </IndexField>
```

Output I'm getting

```
<idxValue>456789 456789 0456789</idxValue>
```

Expected Output:

```
<idxValue>456789</idxValue>
```

Here I have to check the two conditions, one is that if there is having multiple `<PolicyNum>` having same value the first value should pick and another is if there is having only one `<PolicyNum>` and its value start with `0` it should be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking LMC's answer I think your code could simply be reduced to :

```
<IndexField>
  <idxName>Number</idxName>
  <idxValue>
  <xsl:value-of select="(PlanMaps/_PlanMaps/PolicyNum[not(starts-with(., '0'))])[1]"/>
  </idxValue>
</IndexField>
```

This will not output anything if there is only one value that starts with zero and will output the first value not starting with zero if there are multiple values.

Answer (score -1):

`xsl:value-of` should use the same xpath as `xsl:when`.

XPath to get first element in the node set

`(//PlanMaps/_PlanMaps/PolicyNum[not(starts-with(., '0'))])[1]/text()`